# request.getParameter return null in jsp by applying java

Tags: javascript, jsp, post, getparameter

everyone.
I am a new Java leaner. I just encounter a problem while trying to get the the Parameter in JSP.
Here is the code :

```
<%@ page language="java" contentType="text/html; charset=ISO-8859-1"
    pageEncoding="ISO-8859-1"%>
 <%@ page import="Rocky.testRocky" %>
<!DOCTYPE html PUBLIC "-//W3C//DTD HTML 4.01 Transitional//EN" "http://www.w3.org/TR/html4/loose.dtd">
<html>
<head>
<script>
function clickMouse()
{   alert("hello");
    <% 
    String fn=request.getParameter ("first_name");
    %>
    var m="<%=fn%>";
    alert(m);
}
</script>
</head>
<body style="margin:0px;">

<label id="coordiv" style="width:80px;height:20px;background:#DDDDDD"  onmousemove="changeColor(id)" onmouseout="clearCo(id)" onClick="clickMouse(id)" >last week</label>

<form  action="test3.jsp" id="myForm" method="post" onsubmit="clickMouse()">
        First Name: <input type="text" name="first_name" >
   <input  type="submit" name="hello" value="Submit">
</form>


</body>
</html>
```

the alert(m) will always be null.
Can someone help me?
Many Thanks

Answer (score 1):

Try this code:

```
    <%@ page language="java" contentType="text/html; charset=UTF-8" pageEncoding="UTF-8"%>
    var value="<%=request.getParameter ("first_name")%>";
```

Comment: Sorry, it seems not working. The first time I click the submit button, nothing returns. But if I click the second time ,I will get the result of the previous value, not the current value.

Comment: first tag put top of the page and variable put inside a function.